# Value assigned to variable or variable assigned to name

Tags: terminology

This always confuses me. I hope for help from native English speakers who mind their language.

Let's say I have:

x := 5

I can say "x is assigned 5". Fine. But then I bring in a preposition. Which of the following expresses what happens: "5 is assigned to x" or "x is assigned to 5"?

I can get one intuition by drawing an analogy to "the name is assigned to the value", so that would indicate "x is assigned to 5". But then, I can also say "the value is assigned the name" without the "to", which would indicate that "5 is assigned x" would be right, and I absolutely think that is backwards.

Comment: I would go with "5 is assigned to x" because you can re-assign. If you have multiple assignments: `x:=5; x:=4; x:=3;` then would you say "x is assigned to 5, then to 4, then to 3", or "5 is assigned to x, then 4 is assigned to x, then 3 is assigned to x". But, there are also better phrases in English (in my opinion), such as "x gets a value of 5" or "x points to something" in case of pointers/references/handles. Disclaimer: I am not a native speaker, but spoke enough of it. Sometimes native speakers get so lazy at using the language they know so well, that they fvck it up too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a native english speaker, but I think It's roughly the same as "John has been assigned the role R"  ( = "the role R has been assigned to John"). In your example, I'd say "the value 5 is assigned to X", or (a little more confusing) "X is assigned the value 5".

Comment: Ah, thanks! The others are saying the same thing, but yours is the explanation I can really get. "John is assigned the task of painting the house" is the same as "The task of painting the house is assigned to John". So the preposition switches the order around. As I suspected.

Answer (score 1):

I would read this as "the value 5 is assigned to the variable x".

Or, in your terminology - the *literal* value 5 is assigned to the variable named x.

Answer (score 1):

The value of X is 5.  5 is assigned to x.

This of it this way.  5 exists.  x := 5, and y := 5.  x isn't assigned to 5, because then that would imply that y can't be assigned to 5.  A variable can at most refer to 1 thing.  So, x can only have 1 value, and y can only have 1 value, right?  5, IS a value.  Many things can refer to 5.

So, it is correct to say that "5 is assigned to x."